# Deleting a file using File.delete() and Uri

Tags: java, android

I am trying to delete a file, but the file is not being deleted and my application is not throwing any errors. Below is my code:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + "howmany.txt");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Boolean k = new File(uri.getPath()).delete();
    if(k){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I put this code right after checking for permissions, and from my understanding, `.delete()` returns true if the action is completed, so if it is I want to display a toast but the toast is never displayed. The strangest thing is that I am not getting any errors, but it just isn't working.

Comment: Why are you converting it to a Uri and then deleting a new File based on that Uri?

Comment: @rabbitguy  got it from some other stack question, should I just take all of the Uri stuff out?

Comment: You can just say `file.delete();` after you create that object and get the boolean back from that

Comment: @rabbitguy wow.... I could have sworn I tried that before. Thanks, post it as an answer and I'll mark it. I ended up just using `Boolean k = file.delete();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a Uri of the file object and then create a file object from that Uri. Just delete the file object and get the boolean result from that. You also don't need to create the `k` boolean. You can just test the delete itself:

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + "howmany.txt");
if (file.delete()) 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```